# Do I always need to add 'if something' in order to avoid 'nil' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Do I always need to add `if @user` in this?

In Pattern 1, it doesn't have `if @user` so it returns 'nil' error when the user was deleted.

In Pattern 2, it won't return 'nil' error but it's too anoying to add this every single line of these things:(

Isn't there any smart way to solve this kind of 'nil' error?
and I just want to display "[Not Found User]" when the user was deleted.

**view/posts/show.html.erb**

```
#Pattern 1
<%= display_nickname(@user.nickname) %>

#Pattern 2
<%= display_nickname(@user.nickname) if @user %>
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def display_nickname(nickname)
    if !nickname.nil?
        return nickname
    end
    "[Not Found User]"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your helper like that:

```
def display_nickname(user)
    user.try(:nickname) || "[Not Found User]"
end
```

Comment: what about view? In my situation, it looks like it absolutely returns error as long as it's nil in view part:(

Comment: Then the error is coming from somewhere else. The `try` wont raise an exception if `user` is `nil`.

Comment: Look at the trace, and check where the error is coming from exactly.

Answer (score 2):

In many, but not all, cases you can use the "try" method from ActiveSupport.

```
foo = Foo.find(1)
foo.bar.try(:some_method)
```

In the example if bar is nil, some_method will also return nil.

So you could do:

```
@user.try(:nickname)
```

Comment: How can I get blank to display nothing in table cell? nil is killing me:(

Comment: Replace your "User not found" with "" in my answer.

Comment: If it's nil then nothing will display, no need for the ""

Comment: Yeah, he's right, if you don't want any text to show up, you can just remove the right part of the `||`.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
def display_nickname(user)
  "#{user.try(:nickname)}"
end
```

or

```
def display_nickname(user)
  user ? user.nickname : ''
end
```

both will print '' if the user is nil, i'd chose the second

Comment: First one looks super smart sophisticated. Thanks!